# 誤訳と違和感: 書式設定の方法サイドバー

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

対象: 質問投稿画面のサイドバーにある「書式設定の方法」

誤訳箇所:

```
__斜体__または****太字****
```

- <s>_ や * でのマークアップを反映させるには前後にスペースが必要なようです</s> [10月1日の更新で、*についてはスペースが要らなくなりました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works)
- _ と * の数が間違っています

その他の項目についても多少違和感があります。

スクショ:

[image: 書式設定の方法]

Answer (score 2):

これはMarkdownの問題です。スペースを間に開かないと解析ができず、そのままに残ります。

改善は検討中です：

1. スペースがなくても、`**`を解析するよう
2. `_`を解析すると、変数名（例：`var_one + var_two`）がvar_one + var_twoになってしまう
3. 手動でHTMLのタグを入れると解決ができる（例：`<em></em>`=`****`, `<i></i>`=`__`)

直せなかったら、ヘルプを更新します。

Answer (score 1):

試訳を質問本文から抜き出しました。それからコードとバッククォートについての項目を追加 (最近サイドバーの中身が変わった?)

```
改行を入れると段落分けになります
段落を分けずに改行するには、行末にスペースを 2 個追加
*斜体*や**太字**にできます
コードを書く時は先頭にスペースを 4 個
バッククォートで記号を`*そのまま*表示`
> を行の先頭に入れて引用
リンクの書き方
....
基本的な HTML も使えます

書式設定のヘルプ »
質問の手引き »
```